# WPF - can't see a button in th View design

Tags: wpf

I wrote a simple WPF window that shows a customers grid.

in the bottom of the grid I added a button "Add a new Customer, but it blended into the background of the window, and I can't see it in View design.

this is the code:

```
<Window x:Class="NihulMlay._1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="                                                                    Customers " Height="120" Width="600">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button  FontWeight="Bold">Customer name</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold">Name</Button>
        <Label Grid.Row="1"></Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
        <Button Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Add a new Customer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="270,114,0,-173" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

thanks.

Comment: What Windows and Visual Studio versions do you use? I can see your Button just fine in VS 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Your Problem is the Window height of 120, once you resize it to say 350, you can see the Button.

The margin on your Button is:

```
Margin="270,114,0,-173"
```

which makes a Top-Margin of 114, the Button height is 100 and the row above is set to 40. This values alone would make a total required height of 254 to see all contents.

Comment: if i set height on "350" i could see the "Add a new Customer" button in the grid. But i want to see it out of the grid on the bottom..

Comment: @ZagGol move it out of the grid definition then. If I understand your question you want to see the button at the bottom of the page. You need to use a grid for the content of the Customer, and then place button in the outer grid and place it at the bottom with vertical alignment. BTW +1 to john for well spotted Margin issue.

Comment: continued, you have probably used designer to place the Button and moved it outside of the Grid. This will **NOT** move the button outside of the grid. It will place it relative to the grid's position if you move the grid the button will move as well. Your best option is to use another container.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mistaking a `Grid` with a `DataGrid`. `Grid` is an area that  contains other **controls** while `DataGrid` Represents a control that displays **data** in a tabular form. Looking at your code sample, I think `DataGrid` is what you wanted.

Assuming you did really mean `Grid`, then you can move your `Button` out by placing the entire `Grid` in another container (e.g. a `DockPanel`) like this:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Add a new Customer" Height="100" Width="139"/>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button  FontWeight="Bold">Customer name</Button>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" FontWeight="Bold">Name</Button>
        <Label Grid.Row="1"></Label>
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```